# Can a seeded shuffle be reversed?

Tags: php, arrays, shuffle

Take this function, which is a seeded Fisher-Yates shuffle (the order is random, but reproducible given the same seed):

```
function seeded_shuffle(array &$items, $seed = false) {
    $items = array_values($items);
    mt_srand($seed ? $seed : time());
    for ($i = count($items) - 1; $i > 0; $i--) {
        $j = mt_rand(0, $i);
        list($items[$i], $items[$j]) = array($items[$j], $items[$i]);
    }
}
```

Can this algorithm be reversed? I.e., given the seed value and the shuffled array, can the array be "unshuffled" into its original order? If so, how?

(The question came up [in the comments here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19658239/generate-predictable-suffled-random-array/19658344#comment37472805_19658344).)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Turns out the answer is yes, and pretty simple:

```
function seeded_unshuffle(array &$items, $seed) {
    $items = array_values($items);

    mt_srand($seed);
    $indices = [];
    for ($i = count($items) - 1; $i > 0; $i--) {
        $indices[$i] = mt_rand(0, $i);
    }

    foreach (array_reverse($indices, true) as $i => $j) {
        list($items[$i], $items[$j]) = [$items[$j], $items[$i]];
    }
}
```

Just generate the same random number sequence using the known seed, and traverse it in reverse.

Comment: in c# https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29522377/reverse-an-array-shufflerandom-to-get-the-original/29524063#29524063

Comment: In Python: https://stackoverflow.com/a/76090245/476